# I am trying to create cookie clicker in python. I have implemented an autoclicker, however, each time I click it adds another autoclicker

Tags: python-3.7

I am fairly new to python and I have challenged myself to create a cookie clicker like game using python and Tkinter. I have just implemented an autoclicker but I am having an issue where each time I click, another autoclicker is added.

I want it so that the user can continue to click, but when the auto clicker is activated, it will automatically add 1 click per second.

I have tried puting window.after(1000, nClick) on different lines as well as adjusting the value. I have tried making new functions but I just can't seem to get it working.

```
import sys
import random
import tkinter
import time


global counter
counter = 0
autoclicker = counter + 1

def nClick():
    global counter
    global autoclicker
    counter += 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter)
    print(counter)
    if counter >= 10:
        autoclicker
        window.after(1000, nClick)

window = tkinter.Tk()
# to rename the title of the window
window.title("GUI")
# pack is used to show the object in the window


mButton1 = tkinter.Button(text = counter, command = nClick, fg = "darkgreen", bg = "white")
mButton1.pack()
mButton1.config(font=("Courier", 44))

window.mainloop()



#input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I expect the counter to automatically + 1 to counter after 10 clicks. It does this until the user clicks again where it automatically adds the click to the autoclicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate out the things "user clicks to add a cookie", "autoclicker adds a cookie", and "turn autoclicker on/off", so there are clear places where those things happen. e.g.

```
import sys
import random
import tkinter
import time


global counter
counter = 0
autoclicker_enabled = False

# autoclicker gets its own function to call, 
# which updates the counter, 
# and calls itself
def autoClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter)
    window.after(1000, autoClick)

def nClick():
    global counter
    global autoclicker_enabled
    counter += 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter)
    print(counter)
    if counter >= 10:

        # autoclicker_enabled is a toggle,
        # so autoclicker can only be enabled once.
        # It starts the autoClick self-loop,
        # and then sets itself so that won't happen again.
        if not autoclicker_enabled:
            window.after(1000, autoClick)
            autoclicker_enabled = True


window = tkinter.Tk()
# to rename the title of the window
window.title("GUI")
# pack is used to show the object in the window


mButton1 = tkinter.Button(text = counter, command = nClick, fg = "darkgreen", bg = "white")
mButton1.pack()
mButton1.config(font=("Courier", 44))

window.mainloop()
```

You can then see that the autoClick function does not print the text as well, and that the counter increase and button text change code is repeated, and maybe move that out to its own function, which both clicks use..